# Magento Installation

Tags: php, magento

Hai

Is it possible to install magento in a local server and access it in to another system in the same network.

Thanks in advance ....

Comment: A little more detail on the proposed setup please. Are you talking about using magento with a proxy?

Comment: This should not be tagged html nor phtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes you can. You might need to make sure that you have a port open for access, such as port 8888. Then you just use the IP address of the computer that has the Magento installation, with the port included, for example:

http://127.0.0.1:8888/magento/

Comment: Can you please tell how to check an open port in my system

Answer (score 2):

If your "local server" is accessible via the network, there should be no problem, I suppose -- after all, that's the way Internet works.

The question is : can you access your server from another computer on your network ?

If yes... well, just try with Magento ;-)

The problems that might occur would be related to stuff like firewall, or that kind of things -- and we cannnot guess about those : it'll depend on the setup of your computers and network.

If you are asking this question, maybe it's because you are experiencing some difficulty when doing so ? If so, what is the problem you are having ?

Answer (score 0):

If your system is connected to any local network then you can ping your magento from any system with in that locally connected network

But while accessing from other systems you should not use local host ,you have to use magento installed systems's private ip address instead of http://localhost